# use np.savetxt to save structured numpy array containing string and float

Tags: arrays, csv, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy structured array which contains string and float. I want to save this structured array as it is into a csv file.
The simplified version of my procedure is like this.

```
    structured_array = np.zeros((1,), dtype=[('string','a20'),('float','f8')])
    structured_array['string'] = 'string'
    structured_array['float'] = 0.0
    np.savetxt('foo.csv', structured_array, delimiter=',',fmt='%s,%f')
```

I would expect `string,0.000000` in foo.csv, but it gives me `b'string',0.000000` where does this quotation mark and this `b` comes from? How can I get rid of it?

I can use `readline()` and manually get rid of this but is there any clever way to do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't replicate... I get  string,0.000000  have you got some sort of encoding set to your script? try ('string','S20') for the first field

Comment: @DanPatterson I can replicate, numpy 1.9.2, and changing to 'S20' has no effect.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde  my version is 1.7.x could this be a Unicode difference issue?

Comment: This looks like [open issue #4543](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4543)

Answer (score 1):

Line 1087 in `savetxt` (...\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npio.py) has

```
for row in X:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

Which reveals that columns are converted to bytes before writing (hence the `b` prefix. It doesn't appear that this can be changed.